# What does article_path mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am quite new to programming and am working my way through the official [Getting Started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). This guides new RoR programmers through a practical Blog application involving CRUD articles that have many comments.

article_path is something that comes up quite often but I have no idea at all at what this does, what it means, how it is used etc.

Here are some examples of how the guide uses article_path:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

(in app/views/articles/new.html.erb)

```
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

(also in app/views/articles/new.html.erb)

```
def destroy
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 @article.destroy

 redirect_to articles_path
end
```

(in app/controllers/articles_controller.rb)

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
 end
```

(in app/controllers/comments_controller.rb)

I would be very grateful for an explanation, as I like to fully understand what a specific line of code does.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`articles_path` will produce something like this `http://yourserver.com/articles` which will be associated with your `ArticlesController` and `index` action.

Consequently `article_path(@article)` will produce something like this `http://yourserver.com/articles/1234567` which will be associated with your `ArticlesController` and `show` action and produce a page for an article with id `1234567`.

You also can do `rake routes` on the command line and see all the details

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand this concept a lot better now

Answer (score 2):

The following in your routes.rb file:

```
match '/articles' => 'articles#index', :via => [:get], :as => :articles
```

Can be invoked my mentioning articles_path. In the above example any request given to domain.com/articles will be mapped to articles#index.  Instead of making request to '/articles' you can just use 'articles_path'

Another Example:

```
match '/articles/all' => 'articles#getAll', :via => [:get], :as => :articles_complete
```

Any request to yourserver.com/articles/all will be mapped to articles controller and getAll Action.  Instead of mentioning '/articles/all', you can just invoke 'articles_complete_path'.  I'm naming articles_complete instead of articles_all to show the convention used.